# KcFinder not work

Tags: limesurvey, kcfinder

I installed limesurvey on my local machine(MacOs), and it worked well.
But then I installed it to Windows server 2008, the kcfinder didn't work well. I want to upload picture, but the buttons didn't work when I clicked them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpxyR.jpg)

The LimeSurvey version is 2.05+ 
Now I found it worked when I use "localhost", but not worked when using IP address.

And javascript console having some error as this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnj0y.jpg)

Comment: i have had this problem as well, try another browser

Comment: Hi, LimeSurvey version and build number + did you have some error in javascript console. Can you upload a picture in the template editor system.

Comment: I found if I use "localhost", kcfinder worked well, but if I use IP address, the buttons are not working

Answer (score 0):

I found that I comment this line($.$.kuki.domain = "config['cookieDomain']) ?>";) in tpl_javascript.php out and it works well. But I'm not sure if it's a good way to solve this problem.